# Discrete Math and Combinatorics: Validity Test

Tags: logic

The main course will be chicken or fish. The vegetable will be carrots and broccoli. We will not have both fish as a main course and broccoli as a vegetable. Therefore, we will not have both chicken as a main course and carrots as a vegetable.

So far this is what I managed to do:

1. p v q
2. r ^ s
3. negate (q ^ s)

Therefore, negate (p ^ r)

Does anyone where I start to prove that it is valid? Is there supposed to be an order of precedence here because I am not sure how I should go about proving this is valid in a orderly fashion.. Thanks to anyone who can help me complete this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the English. Clearly what you're having for dinner is carrots and broccoli as vegetables, and because you won't have fish with the broccoli you're having chicken as the main course. So you're having chicken with carrots and broccoli. Which means you *are* having chicken with carrots.

In short, you'd better not be able to prove that argument to valid, since clearly it's not.

EDIT: If you wanted to approach this in an orderly fashion, the simplest thing you could do is construct a 16-line truth table showing all possible combinations of T's and F's for the four statements p, q, r, and s. Then look for a line that makes all the premises true and makes the conclusion false. If you find one, the argument is invalid; if you don't find one, the argument is valid. You would in fact find that the line T, F, T, T for p, q, r, and s, respectively, showed the argument to be invalid.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of doing a truth table, but that would be a no brainer on an exam so I was seeking for another way of doing it.

Comment: You make "no brainer" sound like a bad thing. There are enough "brainers" in logic so you take your no-brainers when you get the chance.    ;)

Comment: About "another way of doing it": of course there are other ways. The most common thing is to do a derivation. But if an argument is invalid, the derivation method won't tell you that. Eventually it may dawn on you. If you don't know whether an argument is valid or not, there's a technique called truth trees or semantic tableaux which will tell you (for logic at this level) whether an argument is valid or not.